Can't exchange authorization code to access token in eBay
I am following a documentation for eBay API and I have done previous steps by enabling OAuth in eBay app for developer. I have got authorization but I can't exchange it for access token. It keep showing me following error:
{
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request"
}

I have tried running this in my PHP Laravel Controller and in Postman. Getting same error:
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'grant_type=authorization_code&code=v%5E1.1%23i%5E1%23p%5E3%23f%5E0%23I%5E3%23r%5E1%23t%5EUl41XzM6RURBMkI0QkQ3RDZGNzVBNzY3RTRFQjUwODk3REE3QzVfMF8xI0VeMTI4NA%3D%3D&redirect_uri=Muhammad_Tayyab-Muhammad-OTIFTE-epcga',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: Basic TXVoYW1tYWQtT1RJRlRFU1QtU0JYLWNhYzMyODgwMi02ODMwYjc1YzpTQlgtYWMzMjg4MDI1Yjk1LTdjOGQtNDgyMC1iMjQ1LTlmNWQ=',
    'Cookie: dp1=bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**69fc443e^; ebay=%5Esbf%3D%23%5E'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

Link to the doc:
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-auth-code-grant-request.html
I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I can't find official postman collection for ebay API.

Your curl request is fine. It seems your <client_id> is incorrect. When I decoded your base64 encoded OAuth credentials, I got this:
"   uhammad-OTIFTEST-SBX-cac328802-6830b75c:SBX-ac3288025b95-7c8d-4820-b245-9f5d"

You can check it out here.
I replaced the "tab" with "M" and retried then, I got this new error:
{
    "error":"invalid_grant",
    "error_description":"the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"
}

It can be considered as a good progress! I hope it helps you to fix the problem.

Client ID is fine. When I remove a character let's suppose first letter of encoded string, it gives error of invalid client. So client is valid.

If that was not correct earlier, it would have shown same invalid grant message.

Did you try decoding this OAuth token? It obviously has a tab character instead of m character at the first. https://www.base64decode.net/decode/8vCx

Thank you. That was the issue too with space in encoded version. Its resolved. It was from eBay side too.
